# Where are Login, Forgot password pages located in instance - 10.2

Tags: cms-only

I need to customize these default CMS pages, by adding some HTML attributes for the form fields.

`Login`
`Forgot Password`

Please let me know, where they reside.

I tried `/sitecore/login/default.aspx`, `/sitecore/admin/login.aspx` but neither are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forgot password** is in `sitecore/login/default.aspx` file in  section

```
<div id="passwordRecovery" runat="server" style="display: none">
```

**Login** is inside **Identity Server** service by default, in file

> sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Views\Account\Login.cshtml